# Number of rows on each page in print area

Tags: excel, vba, count, row

Is there any way to determine how many rows there are on each page inside my print area on each printed page? There are different amount of rows can be fitted to each page because of "Wrap text" command in my macro. I would like macro to go through whole Print area and count rows could be fitted on each page. My print area is A1:C111.

I have tried to work on this one with no result:

```
Sub t()
Dim printRng As Range, lastRow As Long

Set printRng = Range("A1:C111")
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = printRng
lastRow = printRng.Row + printRng.Rows.Count - 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `HPageBreaks` to get all horizontal page breaks. For each page break you can determine the row number `Location.Row`. If you subtract row number of the page break before, then you get the amount of rows on each page.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountRowsEachPage()
    Dim LastPb As Long
    LastPb = 1 'initialize

    Dim pb As HPageBreak
    For Each pb In Worksheets("Sheet1").HPageBreaks
        Debug.Print pb.Location.Row - LastPb 'shows rows per page on the intermediate window
        LastPb = pb.Location.Row
    Next pb
End Sub
```